# MongoDB Suggestion box / feedback?

Tags: mongodb, feedback

I was looking at MongoDB on GitHub, their site, etc. and I could not easily find where to make an official suggestion. I would think in the issues, but maybe that's blocked if you're not included in a team list or something because it seemed to be missing?
Contact Us area more or less seems to just says go find a User Group of which I'm part of one and just went to a meetup which was presented by @stennie, that was interesting.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/lp/contact/products/development-support

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Jira is more what us was looking for thanks to both of you.

Comment: Posted this Feature request. I couldn't really find a simple place to put it categorically speaking? I ended up putting a feature request for a different kind of shared file system mode into Ops manager software forum. so I failed to find the basic suggestion box easily? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MMS-3313?filter=-2